# Is this the right place for Ubuntu using WSL questions?

Tags: discussion

Is this the right exchange to ask about networking problems Ubuntu using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)? It seems like candidates are here, “Unix & Linux,” and “Ask Ubuntu.”

The question relates to a work-from-home situation, not a professionally-managed environment, so “Network Engineering” is probably off the table.

Comment: It would be on topic on [su] but I'm not familiar with the other 2 sites to know if it would be a better fit there. Any any case please don't cross-post to multiple sites.

Comment: @StoneThrow - It would help if you provided the question, for us to review, to better understand the question you want to ask.

Comment: @Ramhound - trying my luck with the question posted here: https://superuser.com/questions/1582623/why-is-there-no-network-connectivity-in-ubuntu-using-wsl-2-behind-vpn -- I guess someone will comment @ me there if there's a better Exchange for it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu using WSL would definitely be on-topic here at Super User. This doesn't mean it would be off-topic in the other sites you mentioned, though - both have tags for [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux). The borders between the different SE sites aren't always clear-cut, and some questions may be appropriate for several sites.